# Show that $\mathcal P(x)\notin x$

Tags: set-theory

Does there exist a set $x$ such that $\mathcal P(x)\in x$, where $\mathcal P(x)$ denotes the power set of $x$?

In Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, the axiom of regularity implies that for all sets $x$ and $y$, we cannot have $x\in y\in x$. Since $x\in\mathcal P(x)$, we cannot have $\mathcal P(x)\in x$, which gives an elementary proof.

However, many authors do not include the axiom of regularity in Zermelo-Fraenkly theory, mainly because almost all mathematical results can be proved without it, and the point of this axiom is basically a matter of convenience.

Therefore, I would like a proof which does not use the axiom of regularity either that we cannot have $\mathcal P(x)\in x$, or that this question is undecidable without this axiom.

In order to prove that this question is undecidable, I tried to show that the existence of a set $x$ such that $\mathcal P(x)\in x$ amounts to the existence of a set $a$ such that $a\in a$, or a set $b$ such that $b=\{b\}$, which (correct me if I'm wrong) are known to be two undecidable questions without the axiom of regularity.

Comment: It's undecidable, of course. Also, authors cannot exclude regularity from presentations of ZF, just as much as you cannot exclude multiplication from the presentation of fields. It's just not ZF without regularity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I trust you that the axiom of regularity should not be excluded from ZF (I'm not an expert in that field), but I have already seen books (very rigorous ones) which do not include regularity in ZF (but still talk about it of course). Therefore I am a bit confused...

Comment: Regularity is not necessary for "everyday mathematics" (read: outside of set theory), so that is not surprising, perhaps. Nevertheless, one shouldn't present ZF without mentioning it, at the very least. And if one does, one should not use the term ZF.

Comment: @Will Can you provide some examples of the books you have in mind that define ZF set theory without including regularity?

Answer (score 4):

As Asaf stated, you cannot prove $\mathcal{P}(x)\notin x$ without the axiom of regularity. However, your strategy could not work for showing the desired independence: it implies the existence of a set $a$ such that $a\in a$, but the possibility that $\mathcal{P}(x)\in x$ leads to a contradiction (so it proves anything) is still opened.

Fortunately, Aczel's anti-foundation axiom, which is known to be consistent with ZFC without regularity, proves the existence of $x$ containing its power set as its element. The main consequence of Aczel's axiom is the Solution lemma:

> **Solution Lemma.** Working with sets with a class $X$, possibly proper, of atoms. If $a_x$ is a $X$-set (i.e. a set which is a *mixture* of other sets and atoms of $X$) then the system of equations
>   $$x = a_x \quad(x\in X)$$
>   has a unique solution $(b_x\mid x\in X)$; i.e. the equality $x=a_x$ still holds if we hereditarily replace $x$ to $b_x$

(see Aczel's [*Non-well-founded set theory*](http://irafs.org/courses/materials/aczel_set_theory.pdf) for its details.)

Consider the following system of equations for $y$:

$$
y = \mathcal{P}(\{y,\varnothing\}).
$$

We can see the Solution Lemma attests the existence of sets $y$, and moreover, $x=\{y,\varnothing\}$ satisfies $\mathcal{P}(x)\in x$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer! :)

Comment: I think it's simpler to use the Solution Lemma to get a set $y$ such that $y = \{\{y\},\emptyset\}$, and take $x = \{y\}$. To motivate this solution: we want to find $x$ such that $x = \{\mathcal{P}(x)\}$. We can't apply the Solution Lemma directly, because $\{\mathcal{P}(x)\}$ is not an $X$-set ($x$ is an atom, so what does its powerset mean?) To fix this, introduce a variable $y$, and set $x = \{y\}$ and $y = \mathcal{P}(x)$. Again, $y = \mathcal{P}(x)$ is not an allowable equation. But now we can substitute $\{y\}$ in for $x$, obtaining $y = \mathcal{P}(\{y\}) = \{\{y\},\emptyset\}$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Good point, I did not see $\mathcal{P}(x)$ does not make sense when $x$ is an atom when I was writing the answer.

Comment: @HanulJeon Of course, the equation you wrote down in your answer is fine, since $y = \mathcal{P}(\{y,\varnothing\})$ expands to $y = \{\{y,\varnothing\},\{y\},\{\varnothing\},\varnothing\}$, and this works, taking $x = \{y,\varnothing\}$. It's just a bit more complicated than it needs to be.